# I am having issues with Importing a class and I'm not sure why its wrong

Tags: java

I have two classes, one is going to be imported into the other. In the first class, the only thing wrong is it is not recognizing my 'enum' the beginning

```
`public class myDate {

    public enum Date {MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY};

    private Date Day;

    public myDate(Day**<--this is considered error** currentDay)
    {
        this.Day = currentDay;
    }`
```

I feel like this is effecting the ability to import this class.

This is my test class. This is the code I wrote. Most of it is fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import myDate.Date;

public class testDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Message");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int enterDay;
        Date currentDay;
        Date nextDay;
        Date prevDay;
        Date calcDay;
        int userChoice;
        boolean loop;

        loop = true;

        myDate day = new myDate(Date.MONDAY);

        while(loop)
        {
            Object[] options = {
                    "Set The Day", "Print The Day", "Return The Day",
                    "Return The Next Day", "Return The Previous Day",   
                    "Calculate The Next Weekday"
        };

        userChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Choose from the actions below", "What is The Day of The Week Game?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

        switch(userChoice)
        {
        case 0:
            System.out.print("Please enter a number 1-7, representing Monday-Sunday");
                enterDay = keyboard.nextInt();
                keyboard.nextLine();
                day.setDay(enterDay);
                break;

        case 1:
            currentDay = day.getDay();
            day.showCurrentDay(currentDay);
            break;

        case 2:
            currentDay = day.getDay();
            day.showCurrentDay(currentDay);
            break;

        case 3:
            currentDay = day.getNextDay();
            day.showCurrentDay(nextDay);
            break;

        case 4:
            prevDay = day.getPrevDay();
            day.showCurrentDay(prevDay);
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.print("Please enter the number of days you want to add to calculate the new weekday ");
            enterDay = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
            calcDay = day.calcDay(enterDay);
            day.showCurrentDay(calcDay);
            break;
        }

    System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Enter 1 for 'Yes' and 2 for 'No'");
        enterDay = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        if (enterDay == 2)
        {
            loop = false;
            System.out.print("YOU SHALL PASS");
        }

        keyboard.close();

        System.out.print("YOU SHALL NOT PASS");

        }


    }

}
}
```

Here is the section that is coming up with the errors. All of the variables assigned to 'Date' and the import 'myDate.Date;' is underlined red and I'm not sure why.

```
 import myDate.Date;  <--- this part comes up as error

    public class testDate {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Message");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int enterDay;
            Date currentDay;
            Date nextDay;
            Date prevDay;
            Date calcDay;
            int userChoice;
            boolean loop;

            loop = true;

            myDate day = new myDate(Date.MONDAY);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and can't) import the field `Date` from the class `myDate`. You could access the `Date` enum with-in the `myDate` class like

```
myDate.Date currentDay;
myDate.Date nextDay;
myDate.Date prevDay;
myDate.Date calcDay;
```

You could also move the `enum` into its' own source file. I would also rename it, there are already `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`

Comment: This helped fix the variables! But  myDate day = new myDate(Date.MONDAY); is still wrong, the *Date* in Date.MONDAY cannot be resolved

Comment: `myDate.Date day = myDate.Date.MONDAY;`

Comment: Also, your `enum` should be `static` (or it must be accessed with a `myDate` instance).

Comment: OK so, I did this (myDate.Date day = myDate.Date.MONDAY;) now my methods are all *undefined for the type myDate.Date*. Do I add myDate.Date to beginning of all methods now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your constructor is wrong:

```
public myDate(Day**<--this is considered error** currentDay)
```

uses the type `Day` when it should be `Date`

```
public myDate(Date currentDay)
```

Comment: ok so this fixed my first class, now basically all lines from 3-22 in the test class are error because 'Date cannot be resolved to a type'

Answer (score 0):

You should import the myDate class and not its method.
Then create an instance of it and access its Date method.

Like,

```
import myDate;
....
myDate mD = new myDate();
mD.Date();
```

Note: The Classes always start with upper-case Letters and methods with lower-case letters.

Comment: The issue is that myDate cannot be resolved. This is the only issue I have now and it's killing me because I dont know how to fix it.